# Google Cloud Pub/Sub C++ Client: Authentication Failure When Binary Has setuid (root) [CentOS7]

Tags: linux, centos7, google-cloud-pubsub

The application (`bin`) loads the (service account) credentials fine when it has "normal" permissions. This is the run script:

```
#!/bin/bash
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/home/user/config/gcloud/key.json
./bin
```

However when `bin` permission are changed:

```
chown root:root bin
chmod u+s bin
```

I get this error:

> E1003 10:02:07.563899584   60263 credentials_generic.cc:35]  Could not get HOME environment variable.
> E1003 10:02:10.563621247   60263 google_default_credentials.cc:461] Could not create google default credentials: UNKNOWN:creds_path unset {created_time:"2022-10-03T10:02:07.563943484+09:00"}

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this is expected behavior for gRPC.  gRPC uses `secure_getenv()` to get all environment variables.  In your case, that means the gRPC ignores the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` set.

You may need to change your application to use explicit service account credentials.  Something like:

```
auto is = std::ifstream(filename);
auto json_string =
    std::string(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(is.rdbuf()), {});
auto credentials =
    google::cloud::MakeServiceAccountCredentials(json_string);

auto publisher = pubsub::Publisher(
    pubsub::MakePublisherConnection(
        pubsub::Topic(project_id, topic_id),
        google::cloud::Options{}
           .set<google::cloud::UnifiedCredentialsOption>(
                credentials)));
```

Comment: Thank you! Running into http proxy issue now `[Retry policy exhausted in AsyncPublish: DNS resolution failed for pubsub.googleapis.com: C-ares status is not ARES_SUCCESS qtype=AAAA name=pubsub.googleapis.com is_balancer=0: DNS query cancelled]`. `setuid` is really making things hard - might need to explore different solutions.